# Couldn't communicate with Google servers

Tags: google-account, google-play-services

Does anybody know how to fix this error? My Android device is a tablet running 4.4 KitKat. I have Google Play Services but for some reason I still can't login or even add a new account. The app giving the error is Google Account Manager, and this all started when I deleted Chrome.Here is what the problem looks like... Except I don't know how to add images....

Comment: What app is giving this error?  When did it start happening?  What version of Android do you have, and what device?

Comment: Hey Matthew,how ya doing? Just more info is this all started when I deleted chrome because I only needed it to download Minecraft apk, then the dreaded com.Google.gapps started popping up

Comment: Hey, I didn't see your comment -- you have to use `@name` to notify someone (so `@Matthew`) -- but fortunately I stumbled across it again.  Thank you for adding the information.  A specific make/model for your device would be helpful.  In the meantime, check this out: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/106494/1465

Comment: @Matthew dude, I've seen that one before, I've literally checked almost EVERY forum I could find this is my LAST HOPE. My device is Maxwest and also I can't download anything from play store, it just keeps saying authentication required and I need to sign in, also I made a new account (before that ) but was having probs with that as well so I removed it and  i can't add a new because of the error and I don't want to remove my account cuz I won't be able to re-add it from the looks of things... And this ALL started because of deleting chrome..........WHYYYYYYYY?!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check of internet connection is reliable and stable.
Try re-logging in to your google account.
Try restarting your device.

If none of the above help, upload a screenshot, so ig is visible, what exactly the problem looks like. (A screenshot can be captured, by swiping the edge of your palm across the screen, right to left).

Comment: Please note that "swiping the edge across the screen" is only applicable to Samsung devices. On most devices, you have to hold volume down+power.

Comment: Sorry, I will know it from now on:)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue n there are many possibilities to what could be causing it:

1. The date may be incorrect in the settings, causing syncing issues.
2. You can install the last version of play store from mirror siteweb

Here is a short easy tutorial I wrote:
[Solutions for most major Playstore problems](http://coding-labs.com/solutions-for-the-most-major-play-store-problems/)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! While it's fine to link your own resources as reference, you [must disclose your affiliation](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). I'll do this now for you, please do so yourself next time. Thanks!