# Screen Orientation not working automatically

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, screen, orientation

My Motorola Moto X screen orientation is not working automatically when I turn my phones in a different direction

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Did You turn on Screen Rotation? Swipe from the top and press the top button. Click the Auto Rotation Option to Turn it on.

Comment: Yes the auto-rotate screen orientation is On.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before. After long day searching and testing apps i found that the G-sensor is not calibrated .you have to calibrate it with mtk engineering app .
Here is a short and easy to follow steps I wrote:

[How to Calibrate G-sensor of android phone](http://coding-labs.com/how-to-calibrate-any-sensor-in-android-phone/)

Comment: I've downloaded the app, but when I click on MTK Settings the response I get is "can not find engineeringmode app" pls what should I do?

Comment: can you try this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.androgames.level  ,
 the MTK if for MTK cpu phones

Comment: ImadOS, please make sure to [disclose your affiliation](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) when linking to your own resources – as I've already [pointed out on one of your other answers](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/149423/16575). If you permanently "forget" this, you risk your posts being deleted as ads/spam/self-promotion.